# Loop through input items onchange with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When a select field is changed, I would like to loop through all of the input values in the form it belongs to using jQuery.  This doesn't work below, but I can't figure out exactly how to do this.

```
$("select.mod").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().get(0).$(":input").each(function(i){
    alert(this.name + " = " + i);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML source or DOM structure for the form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably the selection of the "parent form" that's causing the problem.

The `.parent()` function returns just the immediate parent, which won't let you get the form element if your `select.mod` is nested in a `<p>` or something.

The `.parents()` function returns *all* the parents of the element; but the first one might not be the form tag.  I'd try this:

```
$("select.mod").change(function(){
    $(this).parents('form') // For each element, pick the ancestor that's a form tag.
           .find(':input') // Find all the input elements under those.
           .each(function(i) {
        alert(this.name + " = " + i);
    });
});
```

That still might not help you if you have form elements nested inside each other, but if that's the case you've probably got bigger problems than a jQuery selector...

Comment: `.parent()` in this context returns only 1 element, the direct parent.

In fact he doesn't need the `get` at all because jquery methods work on collections of objects (in this case, a collection of 1).

Comment: Oops, yeah, parent() will just return the direct parent.  That's still probably not what he needs though.  Editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is almost certainly:

```
.$(":input")
```

That doesn't make sense. You're trying to call the `$(":input")` method on whatever `.get(0)` returns... of course there is no such method!

What you're looking for is probably more like:

```
$(this).parent().find(":input").each( ... )
```

Could offer more help with more details. Getting an error? What's the DOM structure? Etc.

Personally, I usually have `id`'s on my forms. So I'd make things clea(r|n)er like:

```
$('#my_awesome_form :input').each( ... )
```

Comment: .find() was the alternative I was looking for. Thanks!